# every view controller has blank space on the right side of the screen

Tags: swift, xcode9

I recently ran the updates on xcode9 and I'm getting blank space on the right side of the screen(about 10px) for every view controllers when I run on the simulators. Is there anyone getting same errors?. I didn't set any specific constraints. I uploadad on github just in case. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

[image: screenshot]

[storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt7Ae.jpg)

Comment: I checked it, I don't have black space on the right on my simulator! Xcode 9.0, iPhone 7 - iOS 11. However, there is a blank space in the home section between the collection view and the tabbar, I assume that you are aware of it...

Comment: if its the black bar then thats one I created. its a blank white space on the right not black. images were supposed to fill the entire width maybe 2px both on the right and left

Comment: I've added a screenshot

Comment: You need to show some code. And possibly a screenshot of what you’re talking about. You can’t expect people to death through an entire project to find what you’re talking about.

Comment: Ah ok. Is that a collection view or table view?

Comment: it's tableview. ignore the black bar on the bottom

Comment: Is this space appears also in the login view controller?

Comment: yes in fact every view controller. the black bar in the image is all the way to the right because I wrote it in code i guess

Comment: And how are you writing it in code? What constraints or layout are you using? Is there an example that isn’t a table view. Just because they are easier to debug.

Comment: its just the black bar that i wrote in code. i didn't set any constraints yet. I'm thinking that might be the problem, but what is there space only on the right when I didn't set constraints? The answer below was fixed after dealing with constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into your project, I noticed that the table view of `SingleViewController` (on the main storyboard) does not has the appropriate constraints, also its size and origin are incorrect. What you should do is to edit the frame (from IB size inspector) of the table view to be:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

Also, you should setup the appropriate constraints for it:

Select the table view and tap "Add New Constraints":

[image]

Note that I added four Constraints: top, lead, trail and bottom with 0 values.

That's should fixed your issue.

Also, I would recommend to setup constrains for *all* of the other views in your project to avoid such an invalid layout...

Comment: I'm not quite getting the problem here. If you see SetMenuViewController, The label "set" is not centered(in Simulator), but It's centered in Storyboard. I was planning on setting constraints after putting all the contents in. So why does it give some space only on the right side when I didn't set constraints?

Comment: "but It's centered in Storyboard" you should not *trust* that, it is not the same case for all devices! Also, if the constraints have been setup right in the cell itself (in conjunction with adding the appropriate constraints to the table view) you should *not* see such an issue. Btw, does it solve your problem?

Comment: yes it solved it! thank you so much! i'll make sure I set constraints for everything now.